# Linq to Sql opposite of OnCreated

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have some code that adds an event handler in the OnCreated method of  Linq to Sql entity class. Where would I go about removing that event handler? Is there some method like OnDestroyed that gets called when the object is garbage collected? Should I use a destructor for this?

This link only mentions the OnCreated method for my purposes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/implementing-business-logic-linq-to-sql

Comment: The purpose is to prevent memory leaks by removing the event handler that gets added in OnCreated. I'm just looking for advice on where/how to remove the event handler.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. What's the purpose of the event handler? Looks like your entity classes have too many responsibilities if they subscribe to events. It's more likely that *that* part should be reevaluated.

Comment: Agreed but there's tons of legacy logic in there that I can't change right now